# Time complexity for detecting a cycle in a graph

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, depth-first-search, cycle-detection

I am trying to understand the time complexity of some efficient methods of detecting cycles in a graph.

Two approaches for doing this are explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/). I would assume that time complexity is provided in terms of worst-case.
The first is union-find, which is said to have a time complexity of O(Vlog E).
The second uses a DFS based approach and is said to have a time complexity of O(V+E). If I am correct this is a more efficient complexity asymptotically than O(Vlog E). It is also convenient that the DFS-based approach can be used for directed and undirected graphs.

My issue is that I fail to see how the second approach can be considered to run in O(V+E) time because DFS runs in O(V+E) time and the algorithm checks the nodes adjacent to any discovered nodes for the starting node. Surely this would mean that the algorithm runs in O(V<sup>2</sup>) time because up to V-1 adjacent nodes might have to be traversed over for each discovered node? It is obviously impossible for more than one node to require the traversal of n-1 adjacent nodes but from my understanding this would still be the upper bound of the runtime.

Hopefully someone understands why I think this and can help me to understand why the complexity is O(V+E).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm, based on DFS, typically maintains a "visited" boolean variable for each vertex, which contains one bit of information - this vertex was already visited or not. So, none of vertices can be visited more than once.

If the graph is connected, then starting the DFS from *any* vertex will give you an answer right away. If the graph is a tree, then *all* the vertices will be visited in a single call to the DFS. If the graph is not a tree, then a single call to the DFS will find a cycle - and in this case not all the vertices might be visited. In both cases the subgraph, induced by all the already visited vertices, will be a *tree* at each step of the DFS lookup - so the total number of traversed edges will be *O(V)*. Because of that we can reduce the time complexity estimate *O(V+E)* of the cycle detection algorithm to *O(V)*.

Starting the DFS from *all* vertices of the graph is necessary in the case when the graph consists of a number of connected components - the "visited" boolean variable guarantees that the DFS won't traverse the same component again and again.

Comment: I don’t understand how the time complexity was reduced from V+E to V. The DFS induced tree obviously has V-1 edges, but we still needed to check some edges that did not appear in the induced tree.